# Identificar variables categóricas y continuas en R

Tags: r, variables, rstudio, categorical

tendo un df de 90 columas y quiero saber cuantas variables categóricas existen dentro de el y cuantas continuas. EL problema es que algunas columnas que contienen números se guardan como tipo chr.
Alguien sabe alguna función para identificar variables categoricas y continuas?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido diego cobra a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Te refieres a identificar variables (que no son factores) pero podríamos considerar que son categóricas?

Comment: exacto, los tipos de variables en mis columnas algunas son tipo numeric y otras tipo character

Comment: Diego, no hay forma de saber si una variable es categórica o no solo mirando los datos, eso lo puede determinar un "humano" que conozca la naturaleza de cada variable. Las columnas tipo cadena son buenas candidatas a ser categóricas, las lógicas sin duda lo son, pero las numéricas ya es otro cantar.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código para ver la clase de cada variable:

(*data* es el dataframe.)

```
library(dplyr)
tipos = data %>% sapply(class) %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(tipo = 1)
```

La librería **dplyr** se necesita para que funcione el pipeline `%>%`. El código genera un dataframe con el tipo de dato en cada columna de data.

Una vez que tengas cada clase puedes manejarlas.